# Google Maps GeoJSON feature trigger click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a featurecollection of features with their corresponding IDs like this:

```
"type"=>"Feature",
    "id"=>"test_1",
    "properties"=>array("desc"=>...
```

and want to trigger a click event from a button on the document so that the infowindow opens.

```
var featId = 'test_1';
map.event.trigger(featId, 'click');
```

but I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined
```

The infowindow opens when I click on the polygon on the map.

Here's a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oavq0pgr/27/).
I've also added a code snippet using stackoverflow's editor.

```js
var mygeojson={
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      'id':'test_2',
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              0.5767822265625,
              46.437856895024204
            ],
            [
              0.560302734375,
              46.160809861457125
            ],
            [
              0.9118652343749999,
              46.10370875598026
            ],
            [
              1.42822265625,
              46.22545288226939
            ],
            [
              0.9118652343749999,
              46.581518465658014
            ],
            [
              0.5767822265625,
              46.437856895024204
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      'id':'test_1',
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              1.9335937499999998,
              46.98774725646568
            ],
            [
              1.8841552734374998,
              46.73233101286786
            ],
            [
              2.581787109375,
              46.53619267489863
            ],
            [
              2.8784179687499996,
              46.71350244599995
            ],
            [
              3.065185546875,
              47.00647991252098
            ],
            [
              2.3785400390625,
              47.18597932702905
            ],
            [
              2.1917724609375,
              47.60986653003798
            ],
            [
              1.9335937499999998,
              46.98774725646568
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
function openinfo(target_featId)
{
 //map.event.trigger(featId, 'click');
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click');
}

initpage = function() 
{
 var selected_id = 0;
 console.log('html loaded');
 //center lat/lon
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.315,0.467);
 
 //map configutations
 var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  scrollwheel: true,
  
 };
 
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("themap"), myOptions);

 map.data.addGeoJson(mygeojson);
 
 map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  //var SD_NAME = feature.getProperty('SD_NAME');
  //var color = feature.getProperty('boja');
  var featId = feature.getId();
  var color = 'gray';
  
  if(selected_id == featId)
  {
   color='#009900';
   console.log('setting green for '+featId)
  } else
  {
   color = 'gray';
   console.log('setting gray for '+featId)
  }

  return {
    fillColor: color,
    strokeColor: color,
    strokeWeight: 1
  }
  
 });
 
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 
 map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
   //var feat_desc = event.feature.getProperty("desc");
    var featId = event.feature.getId();
  map.data.forEach(function(feature2) {
   if(featId == selected_id) feature2.setProperty('color','gray');
  });
    
  selected_id = featId;
  var color = '#009900';

  infowindow.setContent("<div style='width:150px; color: #000;'> litttle test "+featId+"</div>");
  // position the infowindow on the marker
  infowindow.setPosition(event.feature.getGeometry().getAt(0).getAt(0));
  infowindow.open(map);
 });
}
```

```css
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: #fff; color: #bbb; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial;}
#themap { height:100%; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</head>
  <body onload="initpage()">
  
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#" onclick="openinfo('test_1')">Open poly 1</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#" onclick="openinfo('test_2')">Open poly 2</a><br /><br />
<div id="themap">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Automatic down-vote. Why don't you post a [mcve]? How can anyone reproduce the issue with the code you provided?

Comment: Please reopen the question. I somehow posted it without JS fiddle. I added both - JS fiddle AND stackoverflow code snippet. Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully fixed this by using:

```
function openinfo(target_featId)
{
      google.maps.event.trigger(map.data,'click',target_featId);
}
```

and then had a new issue with the addListener function. the event.feature was undefined, so I fixed it with:`if(!event.feature) event.feature=event;` inside `map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {`